# Java compile missing return statement error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I am trying to learning java, by goofing around and creating different things such as this dice example. However, in the class below I am stuck on this missing return, but I am not sure why. All help is appreciated!

Test1.java:12: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
1 error

```
import java.util.Random;

class Char
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int nSides;

    public int Die(int sides)
    {
        this.nSides = sides;
        r = new Random();   
    }

    public int roll()
    {
        return r.nextInt(nSides + 1);
    }

    public int roll(int times)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
        sum += roll();
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to write a constructor, which naturally has no return value. 
A constructor must have the *same name as the class that it constructs*.

Replace `public int Die` with the following.

```
public Char(int sides)
{
    this.nSides = sides;
    r = new Random();   
}
```

Alternately, you can rename your class `Die`.

```
public class Die {
    public Die(int sides)
    {
       this.nSides = sides;
       r = new Random();   
    }
// Rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to say

```
public Char(int sides)
```

or, assuming that you want the class really to be called "Die", change the class declaration to:

```
class Die
```

and the constructor (?) line to:

```
public Die(int sides)
```

(removing the "int").

Answer (score 0):

In function Die apply return statement:

```
public int Die(int sides)
{
    this.nSides = sides;
    r = new Random(); 
    return 0; // whatever you want to return 
}
```

or remove `int` before die and make it `void`.

```
public void Die(int sides)
{
    this.nSides = sides;
    r = new Random(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to create a class called `Die` and that's meant to be its constructor. Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Die {
    private Random r = new Random();
    private final int nSides;

    public Die(int sides) {
        this.nSides = sides;
    }

    // rest of class omitted
}
```

Notes:

- Constructors don't declare a return type and are named the same as the class.
- No need to re-initialize the `Random` field (line removed)
- Better to declare `nSides` as `final` (see code)
- Better to make all fields `private`